# Ubuntu 18.04 SSH VPS continually disconnecting

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, putty

I have a Virpus VPS that is running Ubuntu 18.04. Since I got it a couple weeks ago, I have been having trouble staying connected via SSH. I am able to connect just fine, but it will seemingly randomly disconnect (at different intervals). After being disconnected, I usually have to wait a minute for it to allow me back in. I've used screen to keep my screen session up, and once I get in I can reattach to the screen without issues.

I have tested it on three different networks on three different machines, two running Windows 10, and one running CentOS. On Windows I have tried using PuTTY, WinSCP, a Python SSH library called paramiko, and Git Bash for Windows. On CentOS, I just used the CLI ssh command. All with the same results. I have tried SSH-ing into different user accounts, but the issue persists. I have even tried on my phone (Android 6) using ConnectBot. No luck.

PuTTY says: "Network error: Software caused connection abort"

CentOS CLI says: `packet_write_wait: Connection to 198.167.140.11 port 22: Broken pipe`

I've tried setting Keepalives in PuTTY but this has no effect. Once I lose the connection, I am unable to ping the server, even from a different host. I.E. if I am SSH-ing into the server from Machine A, then I get disconnected, then I immediately go to Machine B and try to ping the server, I get no response. That seems to me like it's the server's fault. On the other hand, if I manually disconnect (cleanly), I **can** ping it.

The Virpus support team says my SSH settings are fine and that they were able to keep a connection (on a Linux box) for at least an hour without problem, after which they manually disconnected. In other words, they can't replicate the problem.

In an attempt to solve the issue, they changed the public IP of the server, but this didn't fix it. Their next step was to redeploy to another node, which seemed to work for a little bit, but now I'm still having the same issue. They told me all they could do now was to redeploy to another node. Since, they've already done this, I'm thinking that won't fix it.

Does anyone have an suggestions? I can post any config info that you ask for, I just don't know what to post.

**UPDATE**:

As requested, here is the output of `ufw status`:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

And for good measure, here is the output of `iptables -L`:
https://pastebin.com/GdScv2rv

**UPDATE:**

I've looked through auth.log and found that I consistently have the following messages consecutively:

```
Nov 10 03:47:04 <hostname> sshd[17618]: Failed password for root from <ip_address> port 44738 ssh2
Nov 10 03:47:05 <hostname> sshd[17618]: Received disconnect from <ip_address> port 44738:11:  [preauth]
```

This is while I am ssh'd in as a different user (not root) but running sudo commands. The `<ip_address>` does not match my host or the remote server.

It also appears that someone is trying to brute-force me because I get a bunch of messages in a row like this:

```
Nov 12 12:21:12 <hostname> sshd[20367]: Invalid user demo from <ip_address> port 49709
Nov 12 12:21:15 <hostname> sshd[20367]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Nov 12 12:21:15 <hostname>sshd[20367]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<ip_address>
Nov 12 12:21:17 <hostname> sshd[20367]: Failed password for invalid user demo from 193.105.134.97 port 49709 ssh2
Nov 12 12:21:17 <hostname> sshd[20367]: Disconnecting invalid user demo <ip_address> port 49709: Change of username or service not allowed: (demo,ssh-connection) -> (root,ssh-connection) [preauth]
```

There are about 1500 and they all use different usernames. I have blocked the IP addresses in `ufw`.

There are also a number of `Failed password for root from` IP addresses that do not match any of mine.

Comment: Firewalling springs to mind; what are your ssh keepalive settings, are you actively doing stuff while you get disconnected?  Those "different networks" you tested with - what makes those "different"?

Comment: In PuTTY, "seconds between keepalives" is set to 3000. I've been disconnected 10 seconds after connected before. "Enable TCP keepalives" is checked, "Disable Nagle's algorithm" is checked. Yeah, it actually seems to happen more often when I am actively doing stuff. One network is my home network behind a router which is behind a modem (I can give more details on request). Another is my network at work which is on a domain, I don't have many details about that one. The third is (presumably) in a datacenter, since it is my web host provider. When I used my phone, I turned off Wifi.

Comment: Possibly a firewall problem; can you add the output of `ufw status` to your question (if your server is using UFW, but AFAIK this is standard on Ubuntu sever)(otherwise `iptables -L`). I had a similar problem where the FW rules would only allow 5 connections/minute from a given IP, and a script of mine (on my PC) would attempt more than that. But this kind of rule shouldn't disconnect an existing terminal session, though.

Comment: @xenoid I added the output of those commands to the question.

Comment: OK, so not a firewall problem. Anything in the SSH logs (/var/log/auth.log)?

Comment: There's a ton. What should I look for? Or should I upload it to Google Drive and link it here?

Comment: @xenoid I added some info from auth.log. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Nasty people trying to get in are irrelevant here (but if you system is not running fail2ban you should consider adding it to keep them at bay...). What you should look for are messages stating your IP or id at the time you get disconnected.

Comment: Maybe your right. I did install fail2ban and also did a bunch more to secure SSH, and it seems to have had some effect. I've been connected for 11 hours and counting.

Comment: Setting a ufw with a limit on the ssh port is a good idea. Personally I also just moved my ssh port to port 2222 as well and that causes all those attempts to completely disappear as well. But as a general rule, instead of doing "ufw allow 22" do "ufw limit 22" which by default restricts it to only 5 attempts per minute. Best is to move to a different port entirely.